# "register" keyword in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I have a large program that uses all the registers I allocated per thread (64) and spills to local memory. I would like to be able to tell the compiler which variables should remain in registers at all cost, and which ones I don't really care about. Does the "register" C/C++ keyword work in nvcc? Is there a different mechanism perhaps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `register` in CUDA C/C++ if you want to. In any context, it is only a hint to the compiler. It may be ignored. There is no stated guarantee that it does anything at all.

I think these statements are pretty much true for most language implementations of `register`.

I also think it's quite likely that the compiler can do a better job than you can of deciding what should be in registers, and appropriate priority.

The typical CUDA C/C++ mechanisms for controlling register usage work at a higher level, they are:

1. the `-maxrregcount` [compile switch](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-steering-gpu-code-generation)
2. the [launch bounds](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#launch-bounds) directive.

Comment: As Roberr Crovella states, the `register` keyword is pretty much ignored by any modern C/C++ toolchain (that includes CUDA's C++ based toolchain) when it comes to register allocation, as they all have sophisticated register allocation mechanisms built in. A compiler may disallow taking the address of a variable with the `register` attribute.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I thought.

_I also think it's quite likely that the compiler can do a better job than you can of deciding what should be in registers, and appropriate priority._
Unfortunately it can't (the computational path is heavily dependent on the data) and it chooses poorly. I can boost the performance significantly by evicting variables manually into global memory. Unfortunately this means that I'm losing the benefits of the L1 cache on them (and it becomes cumbersome to program coalesced accesses) since I'm on CC3.5.

Comment: @Robert Crovella, njuffa
So there is no sure solution except writing all of the accesses to these variables in assembly (I have never done this in CUDA - is this even an option?).

Comment: @AMMC: Thing is, in `PTX ISA 5.1.1. Register State Space` I found the following:
`Registers (.reg state space) are fast storage locations. The number of registers is limited, and will vary from platform to platform. When the limit is exceeded, register variables will be spilled to memory, causing changes in performance.`
So it seems like even if I write handwritten PTX I still have no control over it. Am I missing something?

Comment: PTX is an intermediate code.  It does not prescribe register usage in any guaranteed way.  It still goes through a compilation step (via ptxas or the driver runtime equivalent).  I don't know of any way to lock or prescribe a particular register usage, and there is no way to write CUDA code directly is SASS (GPU assembly code) using any NVIDIA-supplied tools.

Comment: GPU machine code (SASS) is not binary compatible between GPU architectures. While there are no NVIDIA-supported tools for writing SASS, there have been third-party efforts to create such tools. Try an internet search for "Fermi assembler", "Kepler assembler", "Maxwell assembler". If there is a demonstrable significant loss of performance due to sub-optimal register allocation: (1) try the latest CUDA version (2) file a bug with NVIDIA via the form on the registered developer website. Sometimes source code tweaks can achieve the desired result but can't recommend anything without seeing source.